# Camera issues on EVO 4G

Tags: android

My app makes use of the camera. After a lot of optimization, everything works fine on the 10+ other devices I've tested on. On the EVO, however, the app just freezes up when I try to take a photo with the camera. In Logcat, I see `I/CameraService(   70): Unknow capture mode!!` I have no other information really (I can't track down the source code for CameraService). No idea if there is some offensive parameters that I'm setting on the camera or what else...

Sometimes the phone just shuts down completely when I try taking the photo.

Also, I did happen to find others will troubles on the EVO: http://androidforums.com/evo-4g-support-troubleshooting/94822-camera-problem-evo.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you set some invalid camera parameters for this particular device. Make sure that every parameter that you use is supported by testing it first.

You can query the supported parameters with the `Camera.Parameters.getSupported*()` (see [`Camera.Parameters`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html)) methods (e.g. [`getSupportedFocusModes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedFocusModes%28%29).) If the parameter is not contained in the returned list, it is not supported on this device; therefore you can't use it.

Comment: Im already doing extensive checking on every param i set, eg.     `List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
                if(focusModes != null){
                    for(String focusMode: focusModes) {
                        if(focusMode.equals(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
                            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);`

Comment: Ok. Just to eliminate the whole wrong params idea and encirculate the problem: Maybe the device reports something it does not really support. Try using a small sample (e.g. the camera api sample) without altering the params and see if it crashes. If it doesn't, go through all the params you need and see if something happens.

Comment: Good idea. Divide and conquer is generally the best approach with these types of things. Man, the fragmentation of android really rears its ugly head with things like the camera. And how annoying is it that the devices report that they support params which they really dont?! I've confirmed this in the past.

Comment: Was just a guess, not sure if it actually does that. I'm not sure if this is an android issue. Had something similar with my desire once. Maybe it's a htc driver story.

Comment: I mean Android insofar as the inevitable consequence of its "openness" is the fragmentation between device makers. The device manufacturers are free to what they want in terms of hardware, etc. but dont honor the "contract" of returning only those values that are actually supported.

Comment: Was finally able to track down the issue. The HTC device does not like `camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` How else can I accomplish this?

Comment: Uhh, actually: I don't know. Rotation has been a big issue with the whole camera api ever since, and I threw away one app idea because it was too much work to workaround this. Glad to hear it's actually working for most of the devices today. So I'd say edit this into the original question and see if someone with more knowledge comes by.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out that, at least on the HTC EVO 4G shift (and I think it stands to reason, on other HTC devices, or at least the EVOs), `setDisplayOrientation(90)` causes issues. The strange thing is, when the preview first starts, the call to `setDisplayOrientation(90)` clearly presents no problem because it works! The problem is that somewhere, its holding onto this and the device doesn't like it. If I comment it out everything works fine. Problem is, I need the damn display orientation to be set to 90 degrees ;).

Comment: Have you had any luck resolving this? I'm seeing the same issue on other HTC devices (G2 + Thunderbolt) but only when using certain preview sizes (despite that they are supported).